# Accessing private repositories in organizations on Github Enterprise via REST

Tags: node.js, rest, github-api

**Problem**: Need to download a private repository that is within an organization hosted on GitHub Enterprise.

I created a personal access token for my account with scope `repo` and stored it as an environment variable, `GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

I'm using `NodeJS` with the `request` library to make the `GET` request. However, with the following code, I get a `401` response when I run it.

(**Note**: I replaced `<repo-name>` with the actual name of the repository).

**Can someone explain why this doesn't work and point me in the right direction?**

---

**My Function :**

```
function downloadRepository(owner, repository, branch, accessToken) {
  let options = {
     method: "GET",
     url: `https://api.github.com/orgs/${owner.toLowerCase()}/repos/${repository.toLowerCase()}/tarball/${branch}?access_token=${accessToken}`,
     headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'
     }
  };

  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
     if(error || response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log("Could not download repository: %s", response.statusCode);
        return;
     }

     return body;
  });
}
```

---

**My Main :**

```
 const request = require('request');

 let wiki = downloadRepository("deep-learning-platform", "<repo-name>", "wiki", 
    process.env.GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

Comment: could not reproduce, there are few typos in your post `https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/tarball/<branch>` instead of `https://api.github.com/orgs/<org>/repos/<repo>/tarball/<branch>` & `const request = require('request');` instead of `const requests = require('requests');`

Comment: @BertrandMartel I fixed the typos and I'm able to authenticate properly now. However, making a `GET` request to get the wiki of a repository returned a `404`. I've tried replacing the repo name with `<repo>.wiki` and also tried replacing the `<branch>` with `wiki` but the response message is `Not Found`. Is this not supported by the API?