# How can I use the GitHub REST API to access a file's data in a private repository owned by an organization via my personal access token?

Tags: typescript, http-headers, github-actions, access-token, github-api

#### Problem

I am in charge of trying to retrieve the json data from a file in a private repository in my company's organization. I am an owner of the organization, but keep getting either a `404` or `401` error when using my personal access token generated from my GitHub account.

- ###### Why I can't use OAuth

  This node app is going to be used as a part of GH Actions in a repository, and a user won't be able to login to verify access at every push to the repository. Hence why I am looking for a solution using an access token of some sort.

#### Things I tried:

- **Reviewing other StackOverflow questions, all of which were either not relevant, not working, not answered, or were outdated.**

  - [Accessing private repositories in organizations on Github Enterprise via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993131/accessing-private-repositories-in-organizations-on-github-enterprise-via-rest) (Closest one to my problem, no solution)
- I tried enabling all privileges for the access token. (the rest were done with all privileges enabled)
- Switching between raw.githubusercontent.com and api.github.com, adding and removing the `.raw` part of the `Accept` header each time.
- Using each URL with and without the `Accept` header.
- Using `Authorization: "token TOKEN"` and `Authorization: "Bearer TOKEN"` with each URL.
- Using a repository from my own account and that WORKS great with the access token I generated.

#### Code that I'm currently using

```
https
  .get(
    // "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/main/path/data.json", // results in 404 error
    "https://api.github.com/repos/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/contents/path/data.json", // results in 403 error
    {
      headers: {
        // request the v3 version of the api
        Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3.raw+json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        Authorization: `token ${process.env.GH_TOKEN}`,
      },
    },
    res => {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode;
    const contentType = res.headers["content-type"] || "";

    let error;
    if (statusCode !== 200) {
       error = new Error(
         "Request Failed.\n" +
           `Status Code: ${statusCode}: ${res.statusMessage}`
        );
    } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
      error = new Error(
        "Invalid content-type.\n" +
          `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`
      );
    }
    if (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      // consume response data to free up memory
      res.resume();
      return;
    }

    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    let rawData = "";
    res.on("data", chunk => (rawData += chunk));
    res.on("end", () => {
      try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
        console.log(parsedData);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof Error) console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
  })
.on("error", e => {
  console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

#### Sort-of "working" but not ideal solution

What does work is using this URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/main/path/data.json?token=SOME_RANDOM_GENERATED_TOKEN, with the generated token being added after clicking the **Raw** button from the repo page. I don't want to use this token obviously for a production Action.

**How can I get this to work? Is it even possible at this time?**

Comment: Is this enterprise cloud or server? is the repo you're trying to access private or internal? can you try the same using the curl command in the docs? https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/reference/repos#contents (note that i'm referencing the enterprise cloud docs). this would help make your reproducer smaller.

Comment: It's currently server, but is in the process of being moved to an enterprise account. I'm unsure what you mean by internal, but it's a private repository created directly inside the organization. I'll check out those docs.

Comment: If it's server (i.e. hosted on premise) you're not going to be able to query it on the host api.github.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with below request and it works.

```
GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/main/README.md' \
 Authorization:'token <Personal Access Token>'
```

Issue could be in request URL - Looks like you are including **/path/** in request URL which is not required. You need to provide actual path of file, so correct URL will be

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/main/data.json
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean I don't need a path, I have some files I need to access that are not in the root of the repository, but in sub directories.

Comment: @Akados - oh ok. that's correct.. i hope you are specifying actual sub directory details instead of "path/" . Can you please do 2 tesing fo me and share result - 

1) test in postman or any rest client?
2) test with any root directory file, eg. readme.md 

Ideally this should work, as it is working for me

Comment: Yes, I'm not using specifically "/path/". I tested in curl, and I got the data back that I need, in a directory, using my personal access token. Did a test in Node, turns out that my token wasn't being loaded from my environment. Replacing the variable with the key works great with your answer.

Comment: @Akados great news.. finally you discoverd real culprit..